# Unable to add class: org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest in Mahout.0.13

Tags: hadoop, mahout

1)When I run this Random Forest example

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest -Dmapred.max.split.size=1874231 -d inputMahoutExamples/RandomForest/rfsplit/trainingSet/* -ds inputMahoutExamples/RandomForest/glass.info -sl 5 -p -t 10 -o inputMahoutExamples/RandomForest/rfmodel
```

I got this error

```
MAHOUT_LOCAL is not set; adding HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath.
Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop
MAHOUT-JOB: /usr/local/mahout/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.13.0-job.jar
17/08/02 16:55:29 WARN MahoutDriver: Unable to add class: org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.addClass(MahoutDriver.java:237)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:6
```

2)I am working with Mahout-0.13 and hadoop -2.7.2

Comment: Where did this command come from that you are trying to run? It seems as either the classpath is incomplete, or you are missing required libraries.

Comment: from on website I forgot its URL and also I tried this command

Comment: $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $MAHOUT_HOME/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.13.0-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest -d inputMahoutExamples/RandomForest/rfsplit/trainingSet/* -ds inputMahoutExamples/RandomForest/glass.info -sl 5 -p -t 100 -o inputMahoutExamples/RandomForest/rfmodel

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-932

Answer (score 0):

```
 $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $MAHOUT_HOME/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.13.0-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest -d inputMahoutExamples/RandomForest/rfsplit/trainingSet/* -ds inputMahoutExamples/RandomForest/glass.info -sl 5 -p -t 100 -o inputMahoutExamples/RandomForest/rfmodel
```

Also I got same error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I think this problem just with Mahout-0.13.
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same issue.
I think they did not include random forest classifier in their last release (not sure though).
It doesn't show in the documentation. Even their documentation website is still in beta mode.
They mentioned two new classifiers:

```
org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.inmem
```

> In-memory mapreduce implementation of Random Decision Forests

```
org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.partial
```

> Partial-data mapreduce implementation of Random Decision Forests

In order to run the command, I had to download and load version 0.11.0 of Mahout. However, I am now confused. Why should I use it and trust the output whereas it was abandoned by its developers?
In previous releases, they mentioned some bugs that are not related to the algorithms but more to managing performance:

> For now, the training does not support multiple input files. The input
>   dataset must be one single file (this support will be available with
>   the upcoming release). Classifying new data does support multiple
>   input files. The tree building is done when each mapper.close() method
>   is called. Because the mappers don’t refresh their state, the job can
>   fail when the dataset is big and you try to build a large number of
>   trees.

It worked though.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem .I think the problem is happened in latest version because ,Random forest is not included in classification with CLI drivers in [Here](https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/algorithms.html) .I have solved this problem by running on earlier version of mahout i.e. mahout 0.9 .